# How to specify an object property type in Spring.NET

Tags: c#, spring.net

I am trying to create an object in Spring where one of its propertys is of type **object**. Now if I do the following:

```xml
<object id="MyObject" type="...." singleton=false>
   <property name="my_property" value="4">
</object>
```

Then the property **my_property** will be a string object. Is there a way do something like:

```xml
<object id="MyObject" type="...." singleton=false>
   <property name="my_property" value="4" type="System.Double, System">
</object>
```

I know this should probably be done by generics but we can't really add this in now as the person who wrote it didn't think of this at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the 'expression' tag. e.g.

```xml
<property name="my_property" expression="double.Parse('4')" />
```

See the Spring.NET documentation [here](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-referencing-compound-properties)